# How do I install python third party libs on the m1 chip?

Tags: python, pandas, pip, homebrew, apple-m1

The Mac Book Air M1 chip doesn't seem to support pep517 according to the errors of installing third-party libraries with pip or brew. Even using these methods without pep517 downloading the library locally didn't work. How does one circumvent this?

Error from using pip install pandas:

```
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I've tried this:

- pip install `<lib>`
- installing the library locally and trying to install with pip without pep517
- brew install `<lib>`
- openblas installation of lib
- python env on the intel venv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, with a different library but with the same error code for PEP 517, I was using python 3.9 at the time, I checked the docs and found out that it's a problem with the python version for the library, downgraded to Python 3.6 and voila! it worked.
Basically try downgrading to Python 3.6 and check.

Answer (score 0):

Installing python libraries through [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) seems to work. I simply downloaded the installer and could later use the libraries globally. If someone has a better in-depth explanation, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same message when trying to install a different package. I solved by removing the CommandLineTools and installing it again. The steps were:

> sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

wait for command prompt...

> xcode-select --install

This solved the issue for me.